# How to auto-add new values to unique values classification values range?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing, symbology

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.1, ArcGIS Server 10.1 & SQL Server 2008 software.

I am adding the query layer and directly publishing to ArcGIS Server and accessing the map in a JavaScript application. The database is auto-updating in every 2 hour.

I am changing the layer properties (Symbol ----category ----unique values) of the layer but it is not auto-updating in ArcMap for new records and in the REST service.

What I tried:

1. I have tried using geo-processing task but not successful.
2. Auto-rendering option in ArcGIS JavaScript API

So is there any workaround for this? (Should I need to reset the parameters in Geo-processing task?)

[image]

Comment: I mean to say that records are updating in the database but each time I have to change layer properties so that records are classifying in four types so is there any automatic way for this?? thanks in advance : )

Comment: When you say map service do you mean the "result map service"? The one tied to the GP task? I dont completely understand your workflow (gp or no gp)... if GP, maybe this help topic will answer some questions: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Defining_output_symbology_for_geoprocessing_tasks/00570000007t000000/

Comment: @KHibma thanks for your reply.. I want to just update the data with unique values..(If this possible without GP then it will be great)..thanks

Comment: @Sunil: Why you have to re-symbolize everytime the data is  updated? Are some new categories (TYPE) being added? I am assuming you're publishing as MSD?

Comment: @ujjwalesri ..the answer is Yes and those categories and I am representing in JSAPI (3.0) on right hand side (as Legend). The data is updating twice a day and I am representing  data by unique values in JSAPI..

Comment: For clarification: So new categories ARE indeed being added during the database update and you need a method to auto-add those new values to the layer's Unique Values classification values range within your MXD?

Comment: @ChadCooper Yes..you are correct  : )

Comment: @All Currently what is happening is that values are coming from the database but those are not auto-classifying in the arcmap hence not coming in the map service and then my js application..thanks for viewing this question !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at the samples, this is what I would do.  There might be better ways, but this should get you going:

1. Add the data to ArcMap using a simple renderer (no classification)
2. Publish as a dynamic map service, but [enable dynamic layers.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00sq000000n1000000)
3. Consume the dynamic map service within an app built in the Esri JS API.
4. Make use of [GenerateRenderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/#sample/renderer_generate_renderer) to update the renderer on the service.
   *You have the option to draw this either server side or within a feature layer.  I would recommend doing it server side if lots of features or complex geometries involved.*
5. Within this you can make use of a [UniqueValueRenderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/#sample/renderer_unique_value) to get all the current values from the field that you want to symbolise by.

I have done something similar for symbolising a live feed and it works fast and has been stable for awhile now.

The downside of this, is that this functionality is being done by the Javascript application and not by ArcGIS Server on its own.  If you need to serve this symbology up to a number of different client applications (which you indicate is not the case), then you would need to look at an automated publishing workflow [using the ArcGIS Server Admin API.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Example_Publish_a_service_with_detailed_parameters/0154000005rw000000/)

I would encourage you to work through some of the samples and read [the help topics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jshelp/#inside_renderers) around this area..  Take a look at the latest (at time of writing) 3.3 JS API from Esri.  If your data was changing more frequently, I would suggest taking a look at how you can [generate a renderer using  a function.](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/#sample/renderer_feature_layer_function_animate)

Comment: thanks...I think you resolve my problem..I will check and let you know...thanks a lot : )

Comment: thank you for the detail explanation . I am going through the steps and I hope it will work definitely          thanks once again : )

Answer (score 2):

Try publishing a service that has all possible 'types' within the symbology to begin with. You can manually add the types by using 'Add Values' if they do not exist in the layer.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply..I want to make  this process automatically..